# how to get vector from another class in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, inheritance, vector

I am trying to pass a vector `plan` from a `class Administrator`, to a `class User` to use the vector in the report method `void report()` of this last class, but it seems that the vector arrives empty.

I will shorten the code to leave you a structure that can be better understood

**file Administrador.h**

```
class Administrador : public User
{
    public:
        vector<string> VectorAsign();
};
```

**file Administrador.cpp**

```
vector<string> Administrador::VectorAsign()
{
    vector<string> plan = {"one", "two"};
    return plan;
}
```

**file User.h**

```
class User
{
    public:
        vector<string> plan;
        void Report(vector<string> plan);
};
```

**file User.cpp**

```
void User::Report(vector<string> plan)
{
    this->plan= plan;
    for (int i = 0; i < plan.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Date of User::Report" << plan[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

**file main.cpp**

```
int main(){
    vector<string> plan;

    Administrador Admin;
    Admin.VectorAsign();

    User user;
    user.Report(plan);

    return 0
}
```

I've tried a lot, but I can't, is there a better way to pass this vector to another class? thank you

Comment: The call `Admin.VectorAsign()` *returns* a vector, but you ignore the returned value. Instead you use the default-constructed (and empty) `plan` vector in the call to `user.Report()`. It seems you're missing some basic beginners understanding, or skipped a few chapters or classes.

Comment: It seems you can't understand the return value of function `Admin.VectorAsign` and the variable `plan` of function `main`, they are not related in your code.

Comment: no, actually I understood the problem, but I just needed to pass the value correctly, the answer to the question worked, in fact I just had to add a return in a certain section and it gives me the values that the vector has, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VectorAsign returns a vector but you are not storing it into a variable.

```
int main(){
    
    Administrador Admin;
    vector<string> plan = Admin.VectorAsign();

    User user;
    user.Report(plan);

    return 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I added a return in a certain part of the code, in addition to adding line 4 of your answer, I already understand what my mistake was, thanks for the answer!